# Solution to inhomogenous second order differential equation (Quantum Harmonic Oscillator)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

An old paper says the homogenous 2nd order differential equation $\frac{d^2v}{dy^2} - \frac{1}{4}y^2v=0$ has the solution in terms of half order parabolic cylinder equation as 
$$U(y)={e^{-\frac{y^2}{4}}}\Big(1-y+\frac{1}{2}\frac{y^2}{2!}  -\frac{3}{2}\frac{y^3}{3!} +\frac{1}{2}\frac{5}{2}\frac{y^4}{4!} -\frac{3}{2}\frac{7}{2}\frac{y^5}{5!}+...\Big)$$.

So how to solve the inhomogenous equation:$$\frac{d^2v}{dy^2} - \frac{1}{4}y^2v=-\frac{de^{-\frac{(y-y_0)^2}{4}}}{dy}$$
The paper says Abramowitz and Stegun 1965 has it tabulated. I spent quite sometime on that book and I cannot figure it out. Can someone point out how this works out? Thanks.